# Configuring IntelliJ IDEA (Community) for Java like scripting language?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I tried to use the community version of IntelliJ IDEA for a proprietary scripting language similar to Java (and I don't do actual Java development for now) which generally works quite well regarding simple refactoring and type hinting.

Because of mainly two differences in the language (boolean is bool and the API calls don't expect java.lang.String types but API specific ones) each class file is contaminated with several errors, which make it useless to quickly find actual errors in that scripting language using IDEA's inspections.

Examples (shown error by IDEA in the comment):

```
bool boolTypeVariable = true;          //cannot resolve symbol bool
if(boolTypeVariable)                   //Incompatibles types: required boolean, found bool
    nlvm.lang.String str = "a String"; //Incompatibles types: required nlvm.lang.String, found java.lang.String
```

(Other errors arise when using !bool, bool && bool and so on)

Is it possible to ignore just these specific kind of inspections or preferably make IDEA to inspect these as desired with small modifications?

I'm aware that it's possible to define own languages for IntelliJ but I'm mostly targeting for some quick solution (which can be dirty, if it works for that case)

I would also accept a suggestion for another IDE that does supports type hinting, inspections and some basic refactoring when it's easily possible to achieve this there (I just choose IDEA community for that since I'm familiar with PyCharm).

Comment: did you try alt-enter -> disable inspection?

Comment: @vikingsteve It's not available for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

If [disable inspection intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html#d786112e68) is not available it means the error is reported either by the parser (such syntax is not supported) or a validation that can not be disabled (e.g. the class `bool` that must be present in the classpath (i.e. in JDK or module libraries or the `javac` would report the error). To completely remove validation errors you can [disable highlighting for the file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html).